# Undo activities in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Hi I just wanted to know if there is any option in oracle apex to **undo** all the activities done in the last **2** days.

Answer (score 1):

What do you call "activities"?

- if it is your actions in the application (such as modifying interactive reports, adding new items to forms, creating pages, deleting pages, ...) then

  - if you were smart enough, you regularly created **backup** copies of those applications (how? By exporting them into .SQL files) so you can now import them back so that they would replace current versions
  - if not, you still have option to **export** application as of "n" **minutes** ago. *Minutes* would in your case be 2.880 which is quite a lot. That option uses the `dbms_flashback` package and `undo` tablespace, so - if there were a lot of operations in between, there's a good chance that you can't get that "old" version of the application
- if it is about changes you did to data (updated some values, deleted rows, inserted new ones, performed calculations, ...), then - as above
- I hope you have backup so that you could retrieve old data (probably not into the same schema but another, and then you'd have to see what to do with which table(s)).

  - also, maybe flashback would help; you'd use it as e.g.

    ```
    select *
    from emp
    as of timestamp to_date('06.05.2021 09:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')
    ```

    but - if there were a lot of transactions since that date/time, maybe you can't retrieve what you *lost*.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [feature](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/htmdb/managing-application-backups.html#GUID-9BA01FDE-64C3-49DC-8235-EE1AB7F95EA6) called "Application Backups", available on apex 20.1 and later. Check if you have that configured, you probably can restore a backup from 2 days ago. Note that this is your application, it will not revert any dml/ddl.